# How to make the sbt assembly task depend on test

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

When I run `sbt assembly` the tests are not run. How can I make the tests to run before running the assembly task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#assembly-task:

> To run the test during assembly,
>
> ```scala
> lazy val app = (project in file("app"))
>   .settings(
>     assembly / test := (Test / test).value,
>     // more settings here ...
>   )
> ```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for the `app` subproject, but the problem now is that I have multiple subprojects and I would like to run tests for all of them. Only `app` has assembly configured, the others have `.disablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)`.

Comment: Why not run explicitly thetm tests then? `sbt test assembly` for instance.

Comment: No other reason, except laziness :-D